# How foreach this array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How to nicely display the data structure.
Below paste my multidimensional array, please help

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LP] => 1
                    [Produkt] => product1
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [LP] => 2
                    [number] => 157/03/2014
                    [Produkt] => product1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [LP] => 2
                    [number] => 157/03/2014
                    [Produkt] => product2
```

=== My CODE ==============================================

```
foreach ($a as $date) {
    $output .= "\t\t\t<ID>". $date[0]['LP']."</ID>\n";

    second foreach for product {
    $output .= "\t\t\t<Produkt>". Produkt ."</Produkt>\n";
}
}
```

Because I want to have something like this
    1
        -Product1
    2
        -Product1
        -Product2
    3
        -Product1
    4
        -Product1
        -Product2

Comment: you have only one product in the array so why u need 2nd foreach ?

Comment: Because I want to have something like this
`1
  -Product1
2
  -Product1
  -Product2
3
  -Product1
4
  -Product1
  -Product2`

Comment: SO I am not clear of what the actually problem is.  Can you show how you would like the output formatted and how this differs from your current output format?

Comment: @MikeBrant One document from multiple positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it appears that you want your output to be XML, i'd suggest the following code:

```
function arraytoxml($xmlObj,$data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(is_numeric($key)) {
                $key = 'item_' . $key;
            }
            $subnode = $xmlObj->addChild("$key");
            arraytoxml($subnode,$value);
        } else {
            $xmlObj->addChild("$key","$value");
        }
    }
    return $xmlObj;
}

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><return></return>");
$return_xml = arraytoxml($xml,$data);
print($return_xml);
```

Where $data is your associative array.

Comment: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild() [simplexmlelement.addchild]: unterminated entity reference on line $xmlObj->addChild("$key","$value");

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Can you post an example array? i'd like to run some tests on my own environment...

Comment: Ok this is my full code http://pastebin.com/1Ej5yN8L
And csv file: http://pastebin.com/r007ucan

Comment: the eventual goal is to convert the CSV file to an XML file?

Comment: Yes, One document from multiple positions. In example <DOCUMENT> with multiple <POZYCJA>

Comment: I see a potential problem with your CSV file.
When i open it with Excel, i noticed that the CSV file has 6 columns without titles / headings. This could be causing the problems with the parser as it does not know what to do with the data.

Comment: For me, all the columns are heading

Comment: The data are nicely parsed into an array. Just how to display them?

Comment: It works almost like I wanted! Just does not work code $date ['number'], but it works. "$Value['LP']." http://pastebin.com/L4EHeXpj

Comment: First foreach foreach ($xml as $date) {$date[0]['numer']}, second foreach ($date as $pozycja) {$pozycja['numer']. Its works!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($a as $array) {
    foreach($array as $value) {
        echo $value['LP'];
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: @damian: Not given the array you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest foreach loops to get down to the deeper elements of your array.

```
foreach ($a as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $output .= "\t\t\t<ID>". $value['LP']."</ID>\n";
        $output .= "\t\t\t<Produkt>". $value['Produkt'] ."</Produkt>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @damian Sorry, I had the English spelling ['Product'] but it should have been ['Produkt']. Answer edited.